# How to calculate values between three cells using conditional calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am new to this forum and not very new to Excel (not in depth)

I have to perform a calculation for three cells by conditional calculation. so here is the scenario

Column Name: Total Area (Cell Address: A2)
Column Name: Remaining Area (Cell Address: B2)
Column Name: Allotted Area (Cell Address: C2)

As per snap shot:

[image]

**Now when I enter a digit in the A2 And B2, It subtract and put the result in C2. And if I enter a digit in the A2 And C2, It subtract and put the result in B2.**

Can Anyone guide me how to perform this task.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use vba to accomplish this, because entering values over existing formulas will erase them. This is a relatively simple macro to create, if you can consider that as an option

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and paste this into it.
This will enter into the cell the needed formula to calculate what you asked for based on if C2 is blank or not. I recomend making a Button that is assigned to this Macro so you can quckly do it. I am very new to VBA so I hope this helps.

```
Sub Calculate()

If Range("C2").Value = "" Then
Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
Else
Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[1]"
End If

End Sub
```